# Regex pattern to match time like '1h 10m'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a time tracking application which needs to parse a string which can have (but not always) a time in it in one of many formats or combinations. The formats I'm checking for are

- h|hr|hrs|hours
- m|min|mins|minutes

These can be with a space in-between the number and the hour or minutes and can be combined or just one or the other. Some examples:

- 1h
- 1 hour 20 mins
- 2hrs 15 m

The regex for matching the times that I have currently:

```
((\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(h|hr|hrs|hours))?(\s*(\d+)\s*(m|min|mins|minutes))?
```

This works fine if I just pass it the time string without anything before it. My problem is that I want to parse a full text string with the time appearing anywhere in it. Some examples:

- The is a time entry for some work 1h 15m
- 2h 45mins This is a time entry for some work
- This is a time entry 1hour 25 mins for some work
- This is a time entry for some work

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Perhaps, [`((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(?:hours?|h(?:r|rs)?))?(?:\s*((\d+)\s*(?:minutes|mins?|m)))`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ6oB9/2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do with yours is make the plural `s` optional, and add some word boundary tokens.

Try:

```
\b((\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(h|hr|hrs?|hours?))?(\s*(\d+)\s*(m|min|mins?|minutes?))?\b
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! It was the word boundary that I was mostly stuck with, thats a useful new one to remember. Thanks!